# Why does the 'laser' clip through the objects after a certain point. Issues with enemyrects (Space invaders Game)

Tags: python, pygame

EnemyRects list is very finicky
Why does the 'laser' clip through the objects after a certain point. Issues with enemyrects (Space invaders Game)
Here is my code.

Thank you in advance

This is just a segment of my code with areas taken out, such as the functions to create the player and enemy etc.

```
import pygame, io  # Can also list other libraries to import: sys, time, io, random, ...
from pygame.locals import *
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Set up variables for the enemy
enemyRects = []
enemyX = 5
enemyY = 30
enemyDiameter = 20
numSegments = 20
enemyMoveX = []
enemyMoveY = []
enemyAlive = []

for i in range(numSegments):
    enemyAlive.append(True)

numShots = 0
maxShots = 4
laserRects = []
for i in range(maxShots):
    laserRects.append(pygame.Rect(-5, -10, 5, 10))

for e in range(numSegments):
    enemyRects.append(pygame.Rect(enemyX + (e * (enemyDiameter + 4)), enemyY, enemyDiameter, enemyDiameter))
    enemyMoveX.append(2)
    enemyMoveY.append(0)

# Shield Variables

shieldOn = False
shieldTimer = 90

wallOn = False

# run the game loop
while True:

    # Draw the image to the background
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(backgroundImg, (0, 0))

    # Move each segment of the enemy
    for i in range(len(enemyRects)):
        if (enemyRects[i].left < 0 or enemyRects[i].right > winWid):
            enemyMoveX[i] *= -1
            enemyMoveY[i] = enemyDiameter - 2

        enemyRects[i] = enemyRects[i].move(enemyMoveX[i], enemyMoveY[i])
        enemyMoveY[i] = 0

    for i in range(maxShots):
        laserRects[i] = laserRects[i].move(0, -5)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, laserRects[i])

    for i in range(len(laserRects)):
        for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
            if laserRects[i].colliderect(enemyRects[j]) and enemyAlive[i] == True:
                enemyAlive[i] = False
                laserRects[i].bottom = -1

    # Draw the enemy
    for i in range(len(enemyRects)):
        if enemyAlive[i] == True:
            drawEnemy(DISPLAYSURF, enemyRects[i])

    # Draw the player
    drawPlayer(DISPLAYSURF, playerX, playerY, 10)

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Thank you

Comment: You have a list for the enemy rects, one for their moving x, one for their y, and one for if they are alive, i think its time for a class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the collision with the lasers, you used the wrong variables to get the enemies

```
for i in range(len(laserRects)):
    for j in range(len(enemyRects)):
        if laserRects[i].colliderect(enemyRects[j]) and enemyAlive[j] == True: #also enemyAlive[j] instead of i
            enemyAlive[j] = False #j instead of i
            laserRects[i].bottom = -1
```

otherwise it was getting the laser index so it was always the first 4 enemies disappearing.

Comment: @Ian139 No problem, i would highly recommend using a class tho, it would make your code look cleaner and more readable. Also don't forget to accept the answer.